# Text is not visible after it downloads the image file with HTML2Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, twitter, html2canvas

[here is the copy of my downloaded file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWjNw.png)

I am trying to download the image using html5canvas, but the issue is it is downloading the file without text.

Here is the snippet of code I am implementing

```
        <script>
            function downloadImage(element = document.body, filename = 'file.png')
            {html2canvas(element, {
                    useCORS: true,
                }).then((canvas) => { 
                    const a = document.createElement('a');
                    a.download = filename;
                    a.href = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
                    a.click();
                });
            }
         </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have mentioned you are using html5canvas but you have applied html2canvas.
Do check it once.

Comment: it was typo , I've fixed